# Cannot read property 'state' of undefined in react app while using redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to build a react redux application in which when I press the add message button, a message is  added to the message array in the reducer's initial state but instead when I compile, I get an error called "TypeError: newstate1.user.id.find is not a function when I press the add message button.
Please bear with me, because I am pretty new to react and redux.

```
import {ADD_MESSAGE,ADD_AUTHOR} from "../constants/action-types"

    export function addMessage(payload) {
      return {type: ADD_MESSAGE, payload}
    };

    export function addAuthor(userName,id){
      return{type: ADD_AUTHOR,payload:{
        userName:userName,
        id:id
      }}
    };
```

Comment: please paste code as code not as img

Comment: there are many, many, MANY questions on Stack Overflow regarding `this` being undefined inside of React event listener functions. Which of them did you try before deciding to ask your own question, and why did they not solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error happen when  u try to assign username to your array. copy this to your files and it will work now:

here to get the array in messages you need to pass a specific property to your action which gonna be `property_id` :

actions file:

```
    import {ADD_MESSAGE,ADD_AUTHOR} from "../constants/action-types"

export function addMessage(payload) {
  return {type: ADD_MESSAGE, payload}
};

export function addAuthor(userName,id){
  return{type: ADD_AUTHOR,payload:{
    userName:userName,
    id:id
  }}
};
```

and now for reducer you need to find the array with this `property_id` with `find()` method.

reducer.js

```
//Reducers produce the state of the application
//State is changed by dispatching an application
import {
  ADD_MESSAGE,
  ADD_AUTHOR
} from "../constants/action-types"


const initialState = {
  messages:[{
    property_id: 12,
    members: [
      "user1",
      "user2"
    ],
    message: [{
        message: "Hello",
        author: "user1"
      },
      {
        message: "How are you",
        author: "user2"
      },
      {
        message: "Whats going on",
        author: "user3"
      },
    ]
  }]
};

function rootReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  if (action.type === ADD_MESSAGE) {
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      messages: state.messages.concat(action.payload)
    });
  }
  if(action.type === ADD_AUTHOR){
    return Object.assign({},state,{
      messages:[{...state.messages.find(el=>el.property_id===action.payload.id),
        members:[...state.messages.find(el=>el.property_id===action.payload.id).members,action.payload.userName]
      }]
    })
  }

  return state;
}

export default rootReducer;
```

list.jsx

here i added a specific property for  each element which  is `id`:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const List = ({ messages ,members}) => {
  return (
    <div>
    <ul className="list-group py-2">
    <h3>available members:</h3>
    {messages.map(el => (
      el.members.map(member=>(
         <li className="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id={el.property_id} key={member}>{member}</li>
    ))))
    }
  </ul>
  <h3>messages:</h3>
  <ul className="list-group  py-2">
    {messages.map(el => (el.message.map(message=>(
         <li className="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id={el.property_id} key={message.author}>message:{message.message} by {message.author}</li>
    ))))
    }
  </ul>
  </div>
  )
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    messages:state.messages
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(List)
```

and for your App.js we pass a second argument for `addAuthor()` which is the `id` of message:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import List from "./js/components/List";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {addAuthor} from './js/actions/index'

class App extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit=()=>{
    this.props.addAuthor("user3",12)
  }
  render () {
   return (  <div>
        <div className="container-fluid">
        <div><List/></div>
         <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Add User</button>
         <p className="text-success">Enjoy</p>
      </div>
    </div>)
  }
}



const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    addAuthor:(userName,id) => {
      dispatch(addAuthor(userName,id))
    }
  }
}

 App = connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App)

export default App;
```

here i passed `id=12` but you can get your id from  component!

Comment: That did work actually and could you help me in adding "user3" to members object inside the initial state. My present action code doesn't work. Its in the reducer picture in my question.

Comment: https://github.com/ajinkabeer/simple-redux-app/blob/master/src/js/actions/index.js     This is the link to my repo, can you take a look? and thanks for your time, I really appreciate it.

Comment: This works perfectly fine if the messages is an object like you changed it to but messages in the initial state is an array, it can't be changed to an object so It doesn't work

Comment: @AjinKabeer please check edited answer! hope this what you looking for and good luck!

Comment: Hi @adel. I've made some changes to my project and I have pushed it to GitHub. Can you take a look now?

Comment: https://github.com/ajinkabeer/simple-redux-app/blob/master/src/js/components/List.jsx

Comment: well this a sandbox of your with a function working add user and sendmessage https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-resonance-mbckh

Comment: It works perfectly! I really appreciate you doing this. If there's any help you want, any day you can count me.

Comment: Hi @adel, I made some changes to by chat component. Now I only have one button which is to add a message when the button is clicked. Can you help me find a way to fix it? . Now, when I press Add Message, the error I get is:  `TypeError: newstate1.user.id.find is not a function
`